# How to animate ListItem in ItemClick?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am having Storyboard in my Page resources to share it between required controls. I try to animate clicked ListItem using that Storyboard in code behind by setting TargetName propery.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Story1">            
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="-200"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>            
    </Storyboard>        
</Page.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="ListView1" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView1_ItemClick">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="GridData">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="GridTrans" X="0" />
                </Grid.RenderTransform>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" />
                </StackPanel>                        
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

private void ListView1_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{ 
    Story1.Stop();
    var item = ListView1.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem) as ListViewItem;
    var grid = item.ContentTemplateRoot as Grid;            
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(Story1, grid.Name);  //???
    Story1.Begin();             
}
```

But unable to animate clicked ListItem on ItemClick event. I get error as "Cannot resolve TargetName GridData"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GridData is under `DataTemplate`, if you use `SetTargetName` method to set animation, it will not get correct `ContentTemplateRoot`. For your requirement, you could use `SetTarget` method.

```
private void ListView1_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Story1.Stop();
    var item = ListView1.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem) as ListViewItem;
    var grid = item.ContentTemplateRoot as Grid;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(Story1, grid);  
    Story1.Begin();
}
```