# uwp dynamic storyboard target name

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I have a `Button` in inside a `ListView.ItemTemplate` which mimicks the behavior of a dropdown button. And I want to give the button a rotation animation by using a `StoryBoard`.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="FolderPathItemArrowAnimation">
    <DoubleAnimation
        By="90"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
        Duration="0:0:0.25" />
</Storyboard>

<ListView
     Background="AntiqueWhite"
     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
     ItemsSource="{x:Bind FolderChain, Mode=OneWay}"
     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StretchListViewItemStyle}"
     Style="{StaticResource HorizontalListViewStyle}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:FolderTree">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Button
                            Style="{StaticResource FolderChainButtonStyle}"
                            Click="PathItemButton_Click" >
                            <Button.Content>
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            Name="{x:Bind Id, Converter={StaticResource FolderChainDropdownButtonNameConverter}}"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Width="30"
                            Click="PathItemDropDownButton_Click"
                            Style="{StaticResource FolderChainButtonStyle}"
                            Content="&#xE974;"
                            FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                            RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" >
                            <Button.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform />
                            </Button.RenderTransform>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Below is the code to start the animation. When running, I get an Exception says that `Cannot resolve TargetName FolderChainItemDropdownButton1`. How can I use `StoryBoard` on `ListView.ItemTemplate`?

```
    private void PathItemDropDownButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(FolderPathItemArrowAnimation, (sender as FrameworkElement).Name);
        FolderPathItemArrowAnimation.Begin();
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid it will not work that update Storyboard from xaml, have you tried create new Storyboard in code behind, or integrate  this animation into your custom button?

Comment: The problem is not about how to create a `Storyboard` but how to let the `StoryBoard` find the item in a `ListView`. So creating Storyboard using code does not work for me.

Comment: Ok, I got it, it looks SetTargetName method can not get correct element where under DataTemplate. please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503329/how-to-animate-listitem-in-itemclick/51510047#51510047) and use `SetTarget` to replace.

Comment: That will solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> get an Exception says that Cannot resolve TargetName FolderChainItemDropdownButton1

It looks `SetTargetName` method can not get correct element where under DataTemplate. please try to use [`SetTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard.settarget?view=winrt-22000) method to replace.

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(FolderPathItemArrowAnimation, (sender as FrameworkElement));
```